# The .jpg is being changed to _jpg for an image name from the database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a script here that somehow changes the .jpg to _jpg.

```
<?php
global $Sys;

//echo $Sys->Auth->chkAuth();
if(isset($_POST['update_slider']))
{
    unset($_POST['update_slider']);
    $post = $_POST;
    unset($_POST);
    foreach($post as $name => $value)
    {   
        $value = (is_numeric($value)) ? $value : intval($value);
        $result = $Sys->db->query("UPDATE dj_photo SET slider_status = $value WHERE name = $name");
    }
    if($result->affected_rows != 0)
    {
        $Sys->Template->setAlerts($result->affected_rows . ' images were added to the image slider.');
    }
    else
    {
        $Sys->Template->setAlerts('No images were added to the slider.', 'error');
    }
}

?>
<div id="webCfg">
<h2>Website Configuration</h2>
  <?php
      global $Sys;

      $alerts = $Sys->Template->getAlerts();
      if ($alerts != '') { echo '<div><ul class="alerts">' . $alerts . '</ul></div>'; }
      $result = $Sys->db->query('SELECT * FROM dj_photo ORDER BY group_name ASC');
    ?>
  <form action="" method="post">
  <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" id="webCfgTbl">
  <tr><td class="label"><label for="submit"></label></td><td class="content"><div class="row submitrow"><input type="submit" id="submit" name="update_slider" class="submit" value="Update Slider" /></div></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <?php
    $i = 1;
      while($slider = $result->fetch_object())
      {
          if($slider->slider_status == 1)
          {
              $add = 'selected';
          }
          else
          {
              $remove = 'selected';
          }
          if(($i % 6) == 0)
          {
            echo "   Slider Name: " . $slider->name;
              echo '<td><div class="adm_slider_pics"><img style="width:180px;height:120px;" alt="' . ucfirst($slider->name) . '" src="../photogallery/' . $slider->img_group . '/' . $slider->name . '" title="' . ucfirst($slider->title) . '" /></a></td><td class="content"><select name="' . $slider->name . '"><option value="1" ' . $add . '>Add</option><option value="0" ' . $remove . '>Remove</option></select></div></td></tr><tr>';
          }
          else
          {
            echo "   Slider Name: " . $slider->name;
              echo '<td><div class="adm_slider_pics"><img style="width:180px;height:120px;" alt="' . ucfirst($slider->name) . '" src="../photogallery/' . $slider->img_group . '/' . $slider->name . '" title="' . ucfirst($slider->title) . '" /></a></td><td class="content"><select name="' . $slider->name . '"><option value="1" ' . $add . '>Add</option><option value="0" ' . $remove . '>Remove</option></select></div></td>';
          }
        $i++;
      }
    ?>
    <tr><td class="label"><label for="submit"></label></td><td class="content"><div class="row submitrow"><input type="submit" id="submit" name="update_slider" class="submit" value="Update Slider" /></div></td></tr>
  </tr></table>
  </form>     
</div>
```

echo "   Slider Name: " . $slider->name; prints this out:

```
Slider Name: DSCF3727.jpg Slider Name: DSCF3687.jpg Slider Name: DSCF3744.jpg Slider Name: DSCF4070.jpg Slider Name: DSCF4071.jpg Slider Name: DSCF4073.jpg Slider Name: 10245379_229236400605097_7329379469957650735_n.jpg Slider Name: 10314007_229236253938445_8056225029697636541_n.jpg Slider Name: DSCF3618.jpg Slider Name: 10550825_261238134071590_1715454340087601479_n.jpg Slider Name: 1551739_261238150738255_2482363522486143465_n.jpg Slider Name: 10626882_284760908385979_3153917771920003400_n.jpg Slider Name: 10689730_284760921719311_8515870397004989019_n.jpg Slider Name: DSCF3384.jpg Slider Name: DSCF3382.jpg Slider Name: biker.jpg Slider Name: 10410927_255245578004179_6557207701489592736_n.jpg Slider Name: 10400847_255245548004182_5319163275713658480_n.jpg Slider Name: 111111.jpg Slider Name: DSCF3013.jpg Slider Name: DSCF4040.jpg Slider Name: 1011255_238047056390698_6002378516798338793_n.jpg Slider Name: 10373785_238048733057197_8255990183542589096_n.jpg Slider Name: 10383572_238047003057370_1041466926744898970_n.jpg Slider Name: DSCF4047.jpg Slider Name: DSCF4051.jpg Slider Name: DSCF4109.jpg Slider Name: DSCF4121.jpg Slider Name: DSCF4136.jpg Slider Name: DSCF4029.jpg Slider Name: Rancho-las-lomas-wedding-DJ.jpg Slider Name: webtest.jpg

<?php
global $Sys;

//echo $Sys->Auth->chkAuth();
if(isset($_POST['update_slider']))
{
  print_r($_POST);
  exit;
    unset($_POST['update_slider']);
    $post = $_POST;
    unset($_POST);
    foreach($post as $name => $value)
```

I add print_r($_POST); after the if and before exit; and get this:

```
Array ( [update_slider] => Update Slider [DSCF3727_jpg] => 0 [DSCF3687_jpg] => 0 [DSCF3744_jpg] => 0 [DSCF4070_jpg] => 0 [DSCF4071_jpg] => 0 [DSCF4073_jpg] => 0 [10245379_229236400605097_7329379469957650735_n_jpg] => 0 [10314007_229236253938445_8056225029697636541_n_jpg] => 0 [DSCF3618_jpg] => 0 [10550825_261238134071590_1715454340087601479_n_jpg] => 0 [1551739_261238150738255_2482363522486143465_n_jpg] => 0 [10626882_284760908385979_3153917771920003400_n_jpg] => 0 [10689730_284760921719311_8515870397004989019_n_jpg] => 0 [DSCF3384_jpg] => 0 [DSCF3382_jpg] => 0 [biker_jpg] => 0 [10410927_255245578004179_6557207701489592736_n_jpg] => 0 [10400847_255245548004182_5319163275713658480_n_jpg] => 0 [111111_jpg] => 0 [DSCF3013_jpg] => 0 [DSCF4040_jpg] => 0 [1011255_238047056390698_6002378516798338793_n_jpg] => 0 [10373785_238048733057197_8255990183542589096_n_jpg] => 0 [10383572_238047003057370_1041466926744898970_n_jpg] => 0 [DSCF4047_jpg] => 0 [DSCF4051_jpg] => 0 [DSCF4109_jpg] => 0 [DSCF4121_jpg] => 0 [DSCF4136_jpg] => 0 [DSCF4029_jpg] => 0 [Rancho-las-lomas-wedding-DJ_jpg] => 0 [webtest_jpg] => 0 ) DSCF3727_jpg
```

I am stumped on this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Gotta love that SQL-injectable code!

Comment: Check for errors, for one thing `$name` should be quoted. That should also be sanitized, or preferably changed to a parameterized query.

Comment: in the database column 'name' its .jpg. So its mysql changing it? I haven't filtered it yet. Its just on localhost at the moment. Just trying to get it to not change the . to a _ lol.

Comment: its .jpg on the form such as the value, but when Update Slider is clicked its _jpg and it hasn't hit the database query yet. That is what I am confused about.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. With the code you've shown this `WHERE name = $name` would never work.. Update/format your question and the pertinent code. If it isn't the database update that the error is occurring at than dont include that code.

Comment: I viewed the source code. Inside the form its correct. When I hit Update Slider after it passes if(isset($_POST['update_slider'])) { its _jpg. I included it because this is the whole script. If i hadn't included it you would be asked where it is and I should have posted it.

Comment: Its changing it before it even gets to the WHERE name = $name. if you notice the print_r($_POST); exit; BEFORE the sql statement. So I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone wondering how to fix this PHP problem (Not Mysqli problem):

Old:

```
if(isset($_POST['update_slider']))
{
    unset($_POST['update_slider']);
    $post = $_POST;
    unset($_POST);
    foreach($post as $name => $value)
    {   
        $value = (is_numeric($value)) ? $value : intval($value);
        $result = $Sys->db->query("UPDATE dj_photo SET slider_status = $value WHERE name = $name");
    }
    if($result->affected_rows != 0)
    {
        $Sys->Template->setAlerts($result->affected_rows . ' images were added to the image slider.');
    }
    else
    {
        $Sys->Template->setAlerts('No images were added to the slider.', 'error');
    }
}
```

New:

```
if(isset($_POST['update_slider']))
{
    unset($_POST['update_slider']);
    $post = $_POST;
    unset($_POST);
    $search = array('_jpg', '_jpeg', '_png', '_bmp', '_gif');
    $replace = array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.bmp', '.gif');
    foreach($post as $name => $value)
    {   
        $column = str_replace($search, $replace, $name);
        $value = (is_numeric($value)) ? $value : intval($value);
        $result = $Sys->db->query("UPDATE dj_photo SET slider_status = '" . $value . "' WHERE name = '" . $column . "'");
    }
    if($result)
    {
        $Sys->Template->setAlerts($result->mysqli_affected_rows . ' images were added to the image slider.');
    }
    else
    {
        $Sys->Template->setAlerts('No images were added to the slider.', 'error');
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer explains neither what the problem was, or how it was resolved.

Comment: Well PHP kept changing .jpg to _jpg so i used a str_replace() to change it back before it got to the SQL statement. Just incase another file extention is used for the image uploaded it will search for those too and change them.

Comment: You have to look at the whole post to know what the problem was. This fixed the problem and its updating properly.